# Assigning a random number to a title which stays the same

Tags: php, xml, random, rss

I am currently pulling XML from an RSS Feed (http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml). 
The RSS feeds has the tags below:

```
//Title of the item
<title><?php echo($item->title); ?></title>


<?php $numbers = rand(100000,999999); ?>
<ID>?php echo $numbers; ?></ID>
```

The ID number when generated works fine, however when the php is refreshed it changes so there isn't a constant ID per item. Is there a method to keep a randomly generated number the same even when refreshed? Or is there a method to assigning a random number to a specific title?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just save it in the session?

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['numbers'] = rand(100000, 999999);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a number once and store it in a 'permanent' location. This can be a Session, Cookie or in the database. I cannot choose for you because I do not have enough information to decide wich of the 3 choices is best for you

Answer (score 0):

The RSS feed doesn't have random IDs. You are inserting a random ID, which you want to not be random. (I don't even know why you want an ID.)

If you just take the numbers from their guid, you would have a unique ID that will serve your needs. All you have right now is a fake ID.

Added: IDs are very rarely 'random' in any sensible project. You want an ID that stays the same. Presumably, you also do not want two stories to have the same ID. Therefore what you need is not a random number, but to assign a random-looking number to each new entry.

You cannot do this without a database (although you could use a flat file database). The table needs two columns - 'ArticleID' and 'RandomID'.

You need to find an item in the feed that is unique and does not change, so that you can recognise it again. News titles do change, so the numbers in the BBC's GUID should be your best bet.

What you then need to do is take this ArticleID number and DB query for a matching row to get an existing RandomID. If there isn't one, keep generating a random number in your current fashion and checking to see if the RandomID is already used until you find a new unused random number. Then insert a new row with ArticleID and RandomID, using the new RandomID for whatever crazy purpose you have.

You could also generate a set of unused random numbers ahead of time. You may also wish to introduce a datestamp or an auto-increment ID so you could more easily delete old article/randomID combinations when eventually necessary.

Comment: Hi Paul, for my purpose the ID has to be random.

Comment: Or, more accurately, have been randomly generated. Updated to outline a methodology.

Comment: Thanks for your time on this Paul, the ideas you've put forward are very interesting. I'm going to attempt to generate a set of random unused numbers. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You could store the number either in a session or if you want to store it permanently and for every user, in a file or a database.

The problem with this is that you would need something to link the stored ID with the item that comes from the RSS feed, which you couldn't do reliably since all the tags contents in the feed could change.

It would work, to some degree, to store both the items title and your randomly generated ID in a file (or database) and then, after refreshing, take the ID based on the items title out of the file (again: or database) again. But if the title of the item changes, the script can't associate any ID with it anymore.